# Angular 2, Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'Injectable' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm new to Angular 2, I did code for social login it running good but i'm getting this error: `Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property Injectable of undefined` ,I tried to solve it but failed, Need help. Thanks in an advance !

**login.component.html**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="signIn('google')" id="googleBtn"><i class="ion-logo-google"></i> Google</button>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from 'app/services/validation.service';
import { AuthServiceLogin } from './../../services/authservice';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from "angular2-social-login";
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [AuthServiceLogin, AuthService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
    error: string;
    loading: boolean = false;
    success: string;
    errorReg: string;
    successReg: string;
    successForgPass: string;
    errorForgPass: string;
    public user;
    sub: any;
    public registerForm;
    public userForm;
    public passForm;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerFormInit();
        this.userFormInit();
        this.passFormInit();
    }
    constructor(public _auth: AuthService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private service: AuthServiceLogin, private router: Router) {}
    registerFormInit() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'name': ['', [Validators.required]],
            'username': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.usernameValidator]],
            'email': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]],
            'password': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.passwordValidator]]
        });
    }
    userFormInit() {
        this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'email': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]],
            'password': ['', [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
    passFormInit() {
        this.passForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'email': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]]
        });
    }
    // ----------- Social Login -----------//
    signIn(provider) {
        this._auth.login(provider).subscribe(
            (data)=>{     
                        alert("login() calling !");
                        this.user = data; 
                        this.sociallogin(data)                                                                                             
                        console.log(data);       
             }
        );
    }

     sociallogin(data){
        this.service.sociallogin(data).subscribe(
            data =>{               
                     alert(" sociallogin() called Successfully ! with token "); 
                      localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.token);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');              
              },
            error =>{
                console.log("User data in sociallogin()"+this.user);
                this.error = "Invalid google Sign in !";

            }
        )
    }
    // -----------#End  Social Login -----------//

    // ----------- Simple Login -----------//
    loginUser(credential) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.error = "";

        this.service.loginfn(this.userForm.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.token) {
                    this.userFormInit();
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.token);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
                    this.loading = false;
                } else {
                  //  this.userFormInit();
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    this.error = data.msg;
                }
            },
            error => {
                this.userFormInit();
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                this.error = "Invalid username or password !";
                this.loading = false;
            }
        );
    }
    // -----------#End Simple Login -----------//

    // ----------- Register User -----------//

    registerUser(credential) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.errorReg = "";
        this.successReg = "";
        this.service.addUser(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.success) {
                    this.registerFormInit();
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    this.successReg = data.msg;
                } else {
                    this.passFormInit();
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    this.errorReg = data.msg;
                }
                this.loading = false;
            },
            error => {
                this.passFormInit();
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                this.errorReg = error.msg;
                this.loading = false;
            }
        );
    }
    // -----------#End  Register User -----------//
    forgetPass(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.passForm.valid) {
            this.service.forgotPassword(this.passForm.value).subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        this.passFormInit();
                        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        this.successForgPass = data.msg;
                    } else {
                        //this.passFormInit()
                        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        this.errorForgPass = data.msg;
                    }
                    this.loading = false;
                },
                error => {
                    this.passFormInit();
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    this.error = error.msg;
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**authservice.ts**

```
import { ControlMessageComponent } from './../home/control-message/control-message.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()

export class AuthServiceLogin {

    private getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        return headers;
    }
    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) { }
    loginfn(credentials) {
        return this.http.post(environment.API_URL+'/public/api/login', credentials, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res.json());
    }
    addUser(data) {
        return this.http.post(environment.API_URL+'/public/api/register', data, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res.json());
    }
    forgotPassword(data) {
        return this.http.post(environment.API_URL+'/public/api/forget', data, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res.json());
    }
    activateUser(userId) {
        let url = environment.API_URL+"/public/api/activation/" + userId;
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res.json());
    }
    changePassword(code, formdata) {
        let url = environment.API_URL+"/public/api/resetpassword/" + code;
        return this.http.post(url, formdata, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res.json());
    }
    loggedIn() {
        return tokenNotExpired();
    }
    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    }   
    sociallogin(data) {
        return this.http.post(environment.API_URL+'/public/api/sociallogin', data, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res.json());      
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpModule, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { provideAuth, AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TooltipModule, ModalModule, AlertModule, BsDropdownModule    } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutesModule, routesComponents } from './app.routes';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { AuthServiceLogin } from './services/authservice';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './home/header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './home/banner/banner.component';
import { ProcessComponent } from './home/process/process.component';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './home/features/features.component';
import { PricingComponent } from './home/pricing/pricing.component';
import { FaqComponent } from './home/faq/faq.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './home/footer/footer.component';
import { TestimonialsComponent } from './home/testimonials/testimonials.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './home/login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { ControlMessageComponent } from './home/control-message/control-message.component';
import { ValidationService } from 'app/services/validation.service';
import { ProfileComponent } from './shared/profile/profile.component';
import { InlineEditorModule } from 'ng2-inline-editor';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';
import { HeaderCoreComponent } from './shared/header-core/header-core.component';
import { FooterCoreComponent } from './shared/footer-core/footer-core.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './shared/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './shared/resume/resume.component';
import { TemplatesComponent } from './shared/templates/templates.component';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';
import { SocialProfileComponent } from './shared/resume/social-profile/social-profile.component'; 
import { WorkExperienceComponent } from './shared/resume/work-experience/work-experience.component';
import { EducationComponent } from './shared/resume/education/education.component';
import { SkillsComponent } from'./shared/resume/skills/skills.component';
import { LanguagesComponent } from './shared/resume/languages/languages.component';
import { InterestsComponent } from './shared/resume/interests/interests.component';
import { ReferencesComponent } from './shared/resume/references/references.component';
import { VolunteerComponent } from './shared/resume/volunteer/volunteer.component';
import { AwardsComponent} from './shared/resume/awards/awards.component';
import { PublicationsComponent } from './shared/resume/publications/publications.component'; 
import { ButtonsComponent } from './shared/buttons/buttons.component';
import { SanitizeHtmlPipe } from './pipe/sanitize-html.pipe';
import { ShareComponent } from './share/share.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { Angular2SocialLoginModule } from "angular2-social-login";

let providers = {
  "facebook": {
    "clientId": "1850828045172034", 
    "apiVersion": "v2.8"
  },
  "google":{
    "clientId": "1005948066107-mp4f1rluvsdog2gu89ho89sjncf1lhek.apps.googleusercontent.com"    
  },
   "linkedin": {
      "clientId": "810ngkn1q263bi"
    }
};

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({}), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routesComponents,
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    ProcessComponent,
    FeaturesComponent,
    PricingComponent,
    FaqComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TestimonialsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ControlMessageComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ResumeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    HeaderCoreComponent,
    FooterCoreComponent,
    SocialProfileComponent,
    WorkExperienceComponent,
    EducationComponent,
    SkillsComponent,
    LanguagesComponent,
    InterestsComponent,
    ReferencesComponent,
    VolunteerComponent,
    AwardsComponent,
    PublicationsComponent,
    ButtonsComponent,
    TemplatesComponent,
    SanitizeHtmlPipe,
      ShareComponent,
      PagenotfoundComponent,



  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutesModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    InlineEditorModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    FileUploadModule,
    MyDatePickerModule ,
    Angular2SocialLoginModule
  ],

  providers:
  [
      {
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
        deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
      },

      ValidationService,
      AuthServiceLogin,
      AuthGuard


  ],


  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you defined this `Inject able`?

Comment: I'm sorry echonax, It's Injectable and it  was my spelling mistake.

Comment: Where's your components constructor?

Comment: constructor(public _auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

Comment: If that's your constructor how does `this.service.sociallogin` work? Where's the `login` method in your service? Can you please post all your relevant code? It's impossible to guess what the issue is like this.

Comment: Please wait Sir.. I'm posting my all code

Comment: I used "npm i angular2-social-login"  package for login and login() comes from it